# How to create ad-hoc network without admin rights

Tags: windows-7, ad-hoc-network

I have a Windows 7 laptop at my work without admin right and it got wifi, is there any anyway to share its internet to my mobile?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS are you running? Windows 7, 8, 8.1?

Comment: You will require admin rights atleast once!

Comment: @BigChris I'm using windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy, you can't. Doing anything that tampers with hardware setup or how a NIC works, requires admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Ad hoc uses network shell commands. These commands require elevated permissions, which mean you need to execute them as an admin, so you just can't as an user.

You could try a physical solution though, like buying a Wifi switch, which will physically share the internet.